# OpenLayers 3 incorrectly transforms coordinates into EPSG:900913

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system, epsg

I've encountered a problem trying to transform coordinates from lat-lon (WGS84) format to EPSG:900913.

Consider the following code:

```
var olCoordinates = ol.proj.transform([55.75, 37.61], "WGS84", "EPSG:900913");
```

This is a coordinates of Moscow I try to transform and it yeilds the result `[6206061.611725002, 4524477.448837536]`.
But on the [EPSG site](http://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=4188137.653801&y=7508562.162509&z=9) i get the other values altogether: `[7508562.162509, 4188137.653801]`.

In other GIS system which we use I get the same values as EPSG site gives me, although it uses OL2, so I assume that there's something wrong either with my setup or with OL3 itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use EPSG:4326 instead of  WGS84. That gives me the correct values.

Comment: That point is no where near Moscow. You probably have the order of the coordinates wrong - longitude, then latitude (X,Y) in most GIS applications.

Comment: That was the case! I indeed swapped lon/lat erroneously. Now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Note you shouldn't use epsg:900913 - its an unofficial code number that Google used because it looks like "google". Use "epsg:3857"  for the web mercator projection formerly known as 900913. See: https://epsg.io/3857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly swapped latitude and longitude. After restoring the correct order everything works fine.